# Создание файла в директории по пути из переменной

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть переменная `directoryFolder` в ней содержится путь к папке который указывает пользователь. Необходимо по этому пути к папке создать файл  в этой папке и наполнить его содержимым `этот текст создан автоматически`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os

directory_folder = r"c:\Folder\file.txt"
folder_path = os.path.dirname(directory_folder) # Путь к папке с файлом

if not os.path.exists(folder_path): #Если пути не существует создаем его
    os.makedirs(folder_path)

with open(directory_folder, 'w') as file: # Открываем фаил и пишем
    file.write("этот текст создан автоматически")
```

Comment: Пользователь будет выбирать путь и по тому пути который он выбрал создается файл и там текст.

Comment: Если путь гарантированно существует, просто убери проверку

Comment: У меня есть интерфейс в котором пользователь выбирает путь. этот путь сохраняется в directoryfolder и потом в той папке которую выбрали необходимо создать текстовый файл с данными